# Which characters of Vālmīki Rāmāyaṇa are also mentioned in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, history, brahmanas, samhita

By characters, I mean people (kings, queens and sages) like Daśaratha, Rāma, Janaka, Sītā, Viśvāmitra, Vasiṣṭha, etc. and not gods/mythological beings like Indra, Agni, Śiva and Viṣṇu.

And by Vedas, I mean all four portions i.e., saṃhitas, āraṇyakas, brāhmaṇas, and upaniṣads but the earliest reference the better.

Comment: Why do you consider these as portion of vedas

Comment: Most of the mahabharata rishis are mentioned in Vedas as well as anukramaki as they were rishis, in ramayana some rishis are mentioned- vishvamitra, vasistha, jabali, Raja janaka.

Comment: I didn't classify or divide Vedas into those parts; it has always been so. @RakeshJoshi

Comment: Ok, maybe you can post an answer citing a few verses from Vedas for each of the sages. Is Janaka of Ramayana same as the Janaka of Upanishads? @Anisha

Comment: @sv. It is propagated by vedantins to support their philosophy. Elsewhere i have posted that what is the technical definition of vedas and what fits in. People even believe geeta or Bhagvata purana as shruti but its not technically..